Verifying Hooke's law through video analysis in a dynamic setup
For educational purposes, I am attempting to experimentally verify Hooke's Law using a dynamic setup analyzed through video footage. In this experiment, a body of mass $m$ is accelerated by a spring. My goal is to determine the acceleration $a$ from the recorded motion and plot it as a function of position $y$. Ideally, this plot should yield a straight line with a slope of $\frac{k}{m}$, where $k$ is the spring constant.
However, I am encountering significant errors in the acceleration calculations due to the second derivative, making it difficult to derive meaningful insights directly from the data. While fitting the data to a sine function (trivially) yields expected results, I question the validity of assuming a sine function over other potential functions that might fit the data equally well. When attempting to plot $a$ against $y$, using other fits, often I do not obtain a straight line, raising concerns about the conclusions I can draw from this data.
Given these challenges, what reasonable conclusions can I draw from my experimental data? Additionally, what improvements can I implement in my setup and data analysis to better support the conclusion of Hooke's Law in this dynamic scenario?
Here is a python code implementing this:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import Polynomial
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

# Load data from the CSV file
data = pd.read_csv('data.dat', delimiter=',')
t = data['t'].values  # Time data
y = data['y'].values  # Position data

# Define the fitting function for the sinusoidal fit
def fitSin(t, A, B, C, D):
    return A * np.sin(B * t + C) + D

# Sinusoidal fit
params, _ = curve_fit(fitSin, t, y)
A, B, C, D = params

# Polynomial fit
poly_degree = 4  # Degree of the polynomial
poly_fit = Polynomial.fit(t, y, poly_degree)

# Create smooth data points
tsmooth = np.linspace(t.min(), t.max(), 2000)
ysmooth_sin = fitSin(tsmooth, A, B, C, D)  # Smooth sinusoidal fit
ysmooth_poly = poly_fit(tsmooth)  # Smooth polynomial fit

# Smoothing the original data using the Savitzky-Golay filter
# Adjust window length dynamically
window_length = min(21, len(y) - 1)  # Must be odd and <= len(y)
if window_length % 2 == 0:  # Ensure the window length is odd
    window_length -= 1
poly_order = 3  # Degree of the polynomial for the filter

# Smooth the data only if enough points are available
if len(y) >= window_length:
    y_smoothed = savgol_filter(y, window_length, poly_order)
else:
    y_smoothed = y  # Use original data if smoothing is not possible

# Function to calculate the first derivative
def first_derivative(y, t):
    n = len(y)
    dy_dt = np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(1, n - 1):  # Middle points
        dy_dt[i] = (y[i + 1] - y[i - 1]) / (2*(t[i + 1] - t[i - 1]))
    dy_dt[0] = (y[1] - y[0]) / (t[1] - t[0])  # First point
    dy_dt[-1] = (y[-1] - y[-2]) / (t[-1] - t[-2])  # Last point
    return dy_dt

# Calculate velocity and acceleration from raw data
v = first_derivative(y,t)
a = first_derivative(v,t)

# Calculate velocity and acceleration for the sinusoidal fit
vsmooth_sin = first_derivative(ysmooth_sin, tsmooth)
asmooth_sin = first_derivative(vsmooth_sin, tsmooth)

# Calculate velocity and acceleration for the polynomial fit
vsmooth_poly = first_derivative(ysmooth_poly, tsmooth)
asmooth_poly = first_derivative(vsmooth_poly, tsmooth)

# Calculate velocity and acceleration for the smoothed original data
v_smoothed = first_derivative(y_smoothed, t)
a_smoothed = first_derivative(v_smoothed, t)

# Plot the data and fits
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(18, 6))

# Plot position data y against time
axs[0].plot(t, y, 'o', label='Measured Position y(t)')
axs[0].plot(tsmooth, ysmooth_sin, 'b-', label='Sinusoidal Fit y(t)')
axs[0].plot(tsmooth, ysmooth_poly, 'g--', label='Polynomial Fit y(t)')
axs[0].plot(t, y_smoothed, 'r-', label='Smoothed Position y(t)', alpha=0.6)
axs[0].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
axs[0].set_ylabel('Position (m)')
axs[0].legend()
axs[0].grid(True)

# Plot acceleration data a against y for the sinusoidal fit
axs[1].set_ylim([-5, 5]) # had to fix the y limits after including the factor 2 in the derivative calculation as pointed out in @KyleKanos comment
axs[1].plot(y,a, 'ro', label='Original Data a(y)')
axs[1].plot(ysmooth_sin, asmooth_sin, 'b-', label='Acceleration a(y) Sinusoidal Fit')
axs[1].plot(ysmooth_poly, asmooth_poly, 'g--', label='Acceleration a(y) Polynomial Fit')
axs[1].plot(y_smoothed, a_smoothed, 'r-', label='Smoothed Acceleration a(y)', alpha=0.6)
axs[1].set_xlabel('Position (m)')
axs[1].set_ylabel('Acceleration (m/s²)')
axs[1].legend()
axs[1].grid(True)

# Adjust layout
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

data.dat
t,y
0.000000E0,1.502285E-3
1.668279E-2,1.502285E-2
3.336559E-2,3.154798E-2
5.004838E-2,4.657083E-2
6.673117E-2,7.078889E-2
8.341397E-2,8.885313E-2
1.000968E-1,1.053235E-1
1.167796E-1,1.228564E-1
1.334623E-1,1.393267E-1
1.501451E-1,1.552658E-1
1.668279E-1,1.680170E-1
1.835107E-1,1.839560E-1
2.001935E-1,1.956446E-1
2.168763E-1,2.057394E-1
2.335591E-1,2.184906E-1
2.502419E-1,2.222097E-1
2.669247E-1,2.243349E-1
2.836075E-1,2.275227E-1
3.002903E-1,2.291166E-1

Output:

Edit: Intuitively if I would use a function similar to sin, but which wiggles "microscopically" around the sin graph up and down like the sketch below, I could match the $y(t)$ data well (also including times larger than T/4), but producing arbitrary large spike in the second derivative.
So what defines the class of "allowed" functions to smooth the $y(t)$ data and what are the physical reasons for it.
Sketch:


I suspect if you tried observing longer than 0.3 seconds, you might find that non-sinusoidal fits have problems

@KyleKanos: Yes that's clear. But shouldn't it work locally?

I don't know what you mean by that; recall that $\sin(x)\sim x-x^3/6+\cdots$, so you cannot necessarily exclude linear & quartic fits from sinusoidal ones in the shorter range.

@KyleKanos: See my edit above.

So what defines the class of "allowed" functions to smooth the $y(t)$ data and what are the physical reasons for it. I don't think there is such a definite class, hence the variety you could find (cf. this Wiki entry).

If you zoom in far enough on most functions, even a straight line often fits pretty well.  Taking more samples over more times really seems like the right call.
